# Javascript code for equations

Tags: javascript, equation

I searched a solution but I keep have the same problem. I have a javascript code that solves a second degree equation. Here there is my code::

```
var x1 = document.getElementById('x1').value;
var x2 = document.getElementById('x2').value;
var x3 = document.getElementById('x3').value;
var x4 = document.getElementById('x4').value;
var x5 = document.getElementById('x5').value;


var discriminant = (x2*x2)-(4*(x1*x3));
if (discriminant > -1){
var x1 = (-x2+Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*x1); 
var x2 = (-x2-Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*x1);
document.getElementById('totx1').value = x1;
document.getElementById('totx2').value = x2;
var temp1 = (x5*x1)+1*x4;
document.getElementById('toty1').value = temp1;
var temp2 = (x5*x2)+1*x4;
document.getElementById('toty2').value = temp2;}
```

For some reasons x1 is correct but x2 gives me a wrong result. Could anyone help me? Here you can see an input example:

2x^2 + 2x - 40 = 0 | y= x4 + x5

The correct solutions are [x1= 4 || y1= 5] and [x2= -4 || y2= -5] but I get [x1= 4 || y1= 5] and [x2= -10 || y2= -9]

Comment: You're re-using the variables x1 and x2, so when the second solution is found, it's using the wrong x1. Don't know if that's related to the problem or just a typo here.

Comment: Reading a value from a text box will always give you a string, you should convert these strings to integers (via `parseInt`) or decimals (via `parseFloat`) before using them in math operations.

Comment: Yeah that is related to my problem, I've just solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parseFloat :

```
var x1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x1').value);
```

And use different variable names for input and output : the fact you reuse `x1` makes this false :

```
var x1 = (-x2+Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*x1); 
var x2 = (-x2-Math.sqrt(discriminant))/(2*x1);
```